# Bind TextBox to DataAdapter

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datatable, dataadapter

.cs

```
    DataTable dt;
    NpgsqlDataAdapter adapter;
    NpgsqlCommand selcmd, upcmd, delcmd, inscmd;
    NpgsqlConnection conn;
    NpgsqlTransaction tran;

    public void ReadAndFill()
    {
        conn.Open();
        tran = conn.BeginTransaction();

        selcmd.Connection = conn;
        selcmd.Transaction = tran;

        dt.Clear();
        adapter.Fill(dt);
        dgMain.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
        tran.Commit();
        conn.Close();
    }
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    { 
        ReadAndFill();
        DataContext = dt;    
    }
```

.xaml

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgMain" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="1" AutoGenerateColumns="False"/>
<TextBox x:Name="textBox" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding name}" Width="120"/>
```

So I can edit only the first row of the DataTable dt through the textBox. And data in textBox does not change when you move on DataGrid dgMain. How to fix it?

Comment: why are you using DataAdapter in the first place? Npgsql supports EF - why not follow the normal MvvM/EF combo dataflow ? Also you're not showing us any viewmodel though you clearly have something bound in DataContext that is providing `name` property eventually.

Comment: i didnt tried it in wpf but in winforms you need to tell the object whats the binded value name and display name, try it.

Comment: Wpf isn't Winform :) trying to transplant things across will only result in misery. Please invest tiny bit of time in learning how to actually do this the right way. This is a trivial thing you're dealing with. Come join us in WPF Chat Room for more guidance: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18165/wpf#

Comment: I do not want to use the MVVM pattern. So I do not want to create a model and view-model. I do not want to create a class to store record of the database table and do not want to work with collection of objects of that class. So I do not want to use EF. I want to work with the data of database  through the adapter/dataset. Can I somehow implement this logic of  work with the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, the TextBox should be tied to the DataGrid. I have not found an example of how the TextBox to bind to DataTable / DataSet / DataAdapter and keep the same logic: data in the TextBox will be changed by moving on DataGrid.